# Integration Services Dashboard - Out of memory

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that generally executes in approximately 7 minutes. Over the past weekend, something went weird and the package took over 19 hours to run. When I go into the Integration services dashboard and try to drill down into "View Messages" to determine what went wrong, I receive an "Out Of Memory" error. I have monitored the memory utilization while trying to pull the report, and the system still shows over 2.5 GB free when the out-of-memory error occurs. SQL 2012 on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't resolve the problem itself, if you want to find the errors, you can query the SSISDB catalog itself. I have the following 3 queries in my favorites list because the other downside you may noticed with the reports in the catalog is that you can't copy useful data out of it.

An error [message type is 120](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877994.aspx)

```
-- Find all error messages
SELECT
    OM.operation_message_id
,   OM.operation_id
,   OM.message_time
,   OM.message_type
,   OM.message_source_type
,   OM.message
,   OM.extended_info_id
FROM
    catalog.operation_messages AS OM
WHERE
    OM.message_type = 120;

-- Generate all the messages associated to failing operations
SELECT
    OM.operation_message_id
,   OM.operation_id
,   OM.message_time
,   OM.message_type
,   OM.message_source_type
,   OM.message
,   OM.extended_info_id
FROM
    catalog.operation_messages AS OM
    INNER JOIN
    (  
        -- Find failing operations
        SELECT DISTINCT
            OM.operation_id  
        FROM
            catalog.operation_messages AS OM
        WHERE
            OM.message_type = 120
    ) D
    ON D.operation_id = OM.operation_id;

-- Find all messages associated to the last failing run
SELECT
    OM.operation_message_id
,   OM.operation_id
,   OM.message_time
,   OM.message_type
,   OM.message_source_type
,   OM.message
,   OM.extended_info_id
FROM
    catalog.operation_messages AS OM
WHERE
    OM.operation_id = 
    (  
        -- Find the last failing operations
        -- lazy assumption that biggest operation
        -- id is last. Could be incorrect if a long
        -- running process fails after a quick process
        -- has also failed
        SELECT 
            MAX(OM.operation_id)
        FROM
            catalog.operation_messages AS OM
        WHERE
            OM.message_type = 120
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Bill! This is exactly the sort of thing I was after!

Comment: This is very helpful. The reports and dashboards only work for packages that pretty much do nothing.